# HTML5 code not running in JSP file

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, weblogic, jdeveloper

I'm trying to drag and drop an object in HTML5 canvas. When i run the code as a .html file from my desktop, it runs perfectly in my browser. When i run the exact same code in a .jsp file then i get no output..To display the output in my web browser from the jsp file I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 as the IDE and Oracle weblogic server as the application server.Does this version of IDE support HTML5??

Another error i'm getting is "Element canvas not expected"

Please help..

Code in .jsp file

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
 <html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>floorplan</title>
<script type="javascript">

var canvas;
var ctx;
var x = 75;
var y = 50;
var WIDTH = 400;
var HEIGHT = 300;
var dragok = false;

function rect(x,y,w,h) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
}

function clear() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
return setInterval(draw, 10);
}
function draw() {
clear();
ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
rect(x - 15, y - 15, 30, 30);
}

 function myMove(e) {
if (dragok) {
    x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
}
}

  function myDown(e) {
   if (e.pageX < x + 15 + canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageX > x - 15 + canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageY < y + 15 + canvas.offsetTop && e.pageY > y - 15 + canvas.offsetTop) {
    x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    dragok = true;
    canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
  }
 }

 function myUp() {
 dragok = false;
canvas.onmousemove = null;
}

 init();
 canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
 canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
 </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
             <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.</canvas>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are restricting with HTML4 using doctype

use this alone "DOCTYPE HTML" in doc type for HTML5.

Comment: that line is automatically being generated by Jdeveloper when i create the jsp file..I'm using Jdeveloper version 11.1.1.7.0...Does this version of IDE support HTML5??

Comment: I'm not sure of the IDE you are using, but most of the latest browser ll do.. go ahead and try out.

Comment: Ya I added <!DOCTYPE html> at the starting of the file and now the code is executing properly..Thanks!!