# jQuery only executes if there is a prior javascript before it (??)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am getting a really weird behaviour where I noticed that jquery only executes if there is a dummy javascript prior to it.

1. With javascript (with alerts command) coded before the jquery scripts

   ```
     <jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
     <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="true" language="java" />
     <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
   doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
   omit-xml-declaration="true" />
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/goeasyhome_logo.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/login.css" />
   <script src="/javascript/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   alert('x');
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[name="j_username"]').focus();
   $('#email input').on("invalid", function(event) {
       if (!$(this).val()) {
           this.setCustomValidity("Please fill in this field 2");
       } else {
           this.setCustomValidity("Please enter a valid email address 2");
       }
   });
   $('#email input').on("change", function(event) {
       if ($(this).val()) {
           this.setCustomValidity("");
       }
   });
   });
   </script>
   </head>

   <body>
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <header>
   <div id="header-center-11x12">
       <img id="goeasyhome_logo_12x12" src="/images/goeasyhome_basic.png"
           alt="goeasyhome" />
   </div>
   </header>

   <br />
   <div id="main-content">
   <form method="post" action="j_security_check">
       <div id="email">
           <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="j_username"
               pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}"
               required="required" />
       </div>
       <div id="password">
           <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="j_password"
               required="required" />
       </div>
       <br />
       <div id="signin">
           <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
       </div>
   </form>
   <br /> <a class="passwdsignup-color" href="/forgotpassword.jsp">Forgot
       Password? </a> <a class="passwdsignup-color signup-position"
       href="/signup.jsp">Sign Up?</a>
   </div>
   ```

When i submit without any data e.g. no email address, the correct validation message pops up as shown below.

[image]

2. With javascripts (alerts command) commented out.

   ```
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/goeasyhome_logo.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/login.css" />
   <script src="/javascript/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
          alert('x'); 
   </script> -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="j_username"]').focus();
    $('#email input').on("invalid", function(event) {
       if (!$(this).val()) {
           this.setCustomValidity("Please fill in this field 2");
       } else {
           this.setCustomValidity("Please enter a valid email address 2");
       }
      });

       :
       :
   ```

[image]

You'll noticed the default message 'Please fill in this field' instead of the 'Please fill in this field 2' is displayed. The jquery command didn't run.

This is bizzare to me.
Any help would be great.

Here's the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yapkm01/3f321g84/

Comment: can you please create a fiddle

Comment: It works in my fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/bikashm/46axLp7L/

Comment: Might be some other issues.

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan what's your jquery version?

Comment: It's jquery 1.12.1

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan Same problem. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Which browsers have you tried? The fiddle works fine for me in Firefox/win

Comment: @Jocie I've tried both firefox and chrome .. same issue

Comment: Curious, are there any errors in the F12 console?

Comment: @Jocie No. Here's the jsfiddle .. https://jsfiddle.net/yapkm01/3f321g84/

Comment: @yapkm01 — No jQuery there.

Comment: @Quentin select the jquery on the javascript function. seems working here but not on my end

Comment: Selecting either jQuery 1.12.1 or 2.2.1 shows the "2" error message for me in Firefox. It might be a daft question, but have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @Quentin i did. same issue .. sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the jquery to the code. I've pasted the whole page here. It works great. Please let me know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="main-content">
        <form method="post" action="j_security_check">
            <div id="email">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="j_username"
                       pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}"
                       required="required" />
            </div>
            <div id="password">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="j_password"
                       required="required" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div id="signin">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <br /> <a class="passwdsignup-color" href="/forgotpassword.jsp">
            Forgot
            Password?
        </a> <a class="passwdsignup-color signup-position"
                href="/signup.jsp">Sign Up?</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //alert('x');
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('input[name="j_username"]').focus();
            $('#email input').on("invalid", function(event) {
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    this.setCustomValidity("Please fill in this field 2");
                } else {
                    this.setCustomValidity("Please enter a valid email address 2");
                }
            });
            $('#email input').on("change", function(event) {
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    this.setCustomValidity("");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? can you check in browser's console?

Comment: @yapkm01 — "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan — "I've pasted the whole page here. It works great." — What did you change to fix the problem? It sounds like you are just saying you couldn't reproduce the problem, which is something you should put in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @yapkm01, you forgot to link jquery. In your fiddle, please go to javascript window, click Javascript button on top right and choose the preferred jquery version and run the code. Good luck.

Comment: @Quentin, it's certainly the problem of not linking jquery.

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan Yeah .. seems working here but still not working on my code .. there's no error on my script console

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan I have added the JSP directive to the top of the code. Could it be due to that?

Comment: Could be <!DOCTYPE html> on the top of the page. What's there in your side?

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan i've modified the code showing the JSP directive .. check it out on the revised code

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like (i.e. in Firefox right click > View Page Source)?

Comment: @Jocie On firefox .. i see <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> highlighted in red .. (almost standard mode doctype .. )

Comment: Can you copy & paste the whole source into you OP? It might be worth trying `<!DOCTYPE html>` (The HTML 5 doc type)

Comment: Not much sure about jsp and html5 :( . But can you have a look into this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147799/why-do-we-need-doctype-to-the-html-jsp-pages
and this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903273/html5-code-not-running-in-jsp-file
Might help you :)

Comment: @Jocie Bingo. Thanks. The <!DOCTYPE html> needed to make this work.

Comment: Glad I and @BikashSinghMaharjan could help, don't forget to accept Bikash's answer!